# In circular way or using circular way

Tags: word-usage, prepositional-phrases, determiners

I bought a face cream yesterday. It had small note about how to apply that cream.  I got confused about following sentence on that note.

> Apply this cream on your face in circular way.

My question is why they use “in circular way”.   If I write that following way, is it wrong?

> Apply this cream on your face using circular way.

Why they use **`in`**? can someone please explain me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In a circular way

or

> in a circular fashion

Or

> Using circular motion.

(with your hands)

These are correct, although I would lean towards the circular motion.

Using a circular way, does not seem right to me, I'm guessing because you need the person to mimic the motion and for that the, other ones on top convey it better, or maybe something else.

Comment: "using a circular motion" would work, too.